# Receiver for Wifi connection on Marshmallow and above

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, wifi, android-broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I have an app that needs to know when the user connects to a specific wifi network. This wifi network may or may not provide the user with internet access.

When targeting Android v25 and below, we could just use a `BroadcastReceiver` that intent-filters for `android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE` in the manifest. As of v26, though, this is no longer the case, it appears. [The documentation states](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts):

> Beginning with Android 8.0 (API level 26), the system imposes additional restrictions on manifest-declared receivers. If your app targets API level 26 or higher, you cannot use the manifest to declare a receiver for most implicit broadcasts (broadcasts that do not target your app specifically). You can still use a context-registered reciever [sic] when the user is actively using your app.

Moreover, Google is requiring app submissions to target the latest API level. So, looks like we have to register the broadcast receiver with a valid `Context`.

My question, then, is how do we run some code *whenever* the device connects to a specific wifi network which may not provide internet connectivity, and not just as long as our `Context` is valid? Is the only solution to register it with a valid `Context`, listen for when that context gets destroyed, set an alarm for a second later that creates a new `Context` and register the receiver again? Seems like the opposite of what they want us to do, but also the only way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JobScheduler to achieve this. Schedule a Job as follows:

```
  JobScheduler js =
      (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
  JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(
    MY_BACKGROUND_JOB,
    new ComponentName(context, MyJobService.class))
      .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_UNMETERED)
      .build();
  js.schedule(job);
```

And perform operation in your `JobService` when OS triggers it. Step by step tutorial to achieve is available [here](https://medium.com/google-developers/scheduling-jobs-like-a-pro-with-jobscheduler-286ef8510129)

Comment: Does this really answers the user's question? Maybe i miss understood but what he wants is a way to implement the broadcast action trigger on STATE_CHANGE and not how to implement a job that only runs if there is a internet connection

Comment: @tiagocarvalho92 `My question, then, is how do we run some code whenever the device connects to a specific wifi network which may not provide internet connectivity, and not just as long as our Context is valid? ` The  solution is JobScheduler

Comment: @Sagar Unfortunately – and I've tested this – `JobScheduler` only triggers the service when the wifi network *has an internet connection*. So, alas, this doesn't satisfy the `network which may not provide internet connectivity` constraint.